# I have added products to cart programmaically and want to show this products on my frontend

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.5

**Add to cart Code**

```
$request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();  
$request->setData($data);  
$cartId = $this->maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId->execute($guestCart);  
$quote = $this->cartRepository->get($cartId);  
$quote->addProduct($productDetails, $request);  
$this->cartRepository->save($quote);
```

**Show cart product to frontend by code**

```
$cartId = $this->maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId->execute($maskedId);  
$quote = $this->cartRepository->get($cartId);  
$quote->setIsActive(1);  
$this->cartRepository->save($quote);  
$result = $this->checkoutSession->replaceQuote($quote);
```

**Where variables**

```
$this->cartRepository = \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface     
$this->maskedQuoteIdToQuoteId = \Magento\Quote\Model\MaskedQuoteIdToQuoteIdInterface  
$this->checkoutSession = \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code:

```
$productId = 1; //Specify product id which you wanted to add in cart and show to frontend.
$product = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId); // Not recommended to use Objectmanager. you need pass this on class constructor
$cart = $objectManager->create('Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart'); 
$formKey = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey')->getFormKey();  
$option = array('469'=>459); // Option if any
$params = array(
                'form_key' => $formKey,
                'product' => $productId, //product Id
                'qty'   =>1, //quantity of product                
                'options' => $option
                );
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();
```

It works for me.